# What does Marlin's G30 code do?

Tags: marlin, ramps-1.4, g-code, z-probe

I'm using Marlin 1.1.0RC8 to control an MPCNC, using a RAMPS1.4. We've just added a touch-plate to do Z-probing, which works nicely for a single probe (I just want calibrated height for variant bit-lengths, not bed-leveling, but I think it amounts to the same thing). I've set it up in Marlin as *FIX_MOUNTED_PROBE*, which seems closest.

I can make it do a `G38.2 Z-50`, `G92 Z12.6` (which sets Z to the height of the touch-plate, 12.6mm), which is ok to be going on with, but it seems I'm having to hard-code the Z offset, which I'm sure should really be set by eg `Z_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER` or `M851`.

My feeling was that I should be able to invoke a G-code `G30`, and it would do a nice fast-slow double tap, do the equivalent of a `G92 Z+zzz` to set that height and then withdraw to a safe height. And after a bit of config, it does exactly that...

... except it doesn't do anything with the height that it measured! Seems odd. The `G30` code seems to be an elaborate way to move the head up by the clearance amount, via a touch-plate (with the added excitement of being able to crash the bed if anything goes wrong)! What's the point?

Have I misunderstood what `G30` is meant to do? I've read [the docs here](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G030.html), and traced through `Marlin_main.cpp` and there really is no "outcome". Unless I've missed something?

Comment: I note that I don't have end-stops on Z, so I can't home/`G28` that axis. I can't see that it makes any difference, but I'll go through the code later and see if that's what's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I believe `G30` is a carry-over from CNC (G-code originated for CNC not printers)
I believe it is for going to a secondary reference (home) position and includes an optional by-way-of address that can be included in the command.

Looking at Marlin 1.1.0-1 (latest release), it seems to do what you said:

1. Move to the requested position (if selected in command, else N/C)
2. Deploy probe
3. Go home
4. Stowe probe
5. Report the requested position and probed Z position
6. Report the current position (home?)

It appears that for Marlin, there is only one reference address (home); so, it would seem a `G30` would be the same as a `G28` (go to primary reference); but, not so.

It looks like `G28` is a home of a different color.  It looks like it homes the axis one-at-a-time and does not support a by-way-of location.  Note that you can select which axis to home by adding the letters 'X' 'Y' and/or 'Z' to the command.

I am not sure what benefit this command has for a 3D Printer other than allowing you to alter the printer's path to home.

Note: Unfortunately I do not have Marlin code up and running on my printer now so I cannot confirm what I am seeing in the code.

Comment: Mark, I haven't forgotten you've written this! Your contrasting of G30 with G28 surprised me so much - I hadn't thought of G30 as a HOME variant - that it made me re-evaluate all my assumptions, and I'm waiting for a rainy weekend to sit down and properly update all my preconceptions! In particular, G30 does "report" the probe position (back to the monitoring app); I was expecting it to store it internally as a reference... will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve recently had a need to use Z-probe touch 
plate on my MPCNC + Ramps 1.4 + Marlin 1.1.5 setup.

Thought I’d share what ended up working for me.

In Marlin `Configuration.h`, I made the changes to enable Z-probe:

```
#define USE_ZMIN_PLUG
#define Z_MIN_ENDSTOP_INVERTING     true
#define Z_MIN_PROBE_ENDSTOP_INVERTING   true
#define FIX_MOUNTED_PROBE
#define PROBE_DOUBLE_TOUCH
#define Z_MIN_POS -100
```

However, the following might be the key to your issue.
`G30` did not do anything for me as well, until I changed 
these values to 0.  The `G30` now lowers Z until the Z probe 
is triggered. I needed to send a `G92` to set the new Z value.
Works like a champ!

```
#define X_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 0
#define Y_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 0
```

In case you’re interested, in ultralcd.cpp under 
lcd_prepare_menu(), I added the a menu item to perform 
the probe.  This way I don’t need a computer to setup 
the machine and launch a gcode file from the sd card.

```
  #if HAS_BED_PROBE
        MENU_ITEM(gcode, MSG_PROBE_Z, PSTR("G30\nG92 Z19.05"));
  #endif
```

Hope this is helpful for you, even after a couple years late.

Comment: It is unclear which parameters are set to zero. If you mean the **probe offset values**, that is **not a good idea**. Note that this question deals with Marlin 1.1.0, in between 1.1.3 and 1.1.4, the `G30` command has undergone a change.